# Form for many to many associations without using the usual Add and remove, but with checkboxes showing all the choices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations, nested-attributes, simple-form

suppose I have three models to express the experience of an employee of programing languages,
Language is a master table, which can not be edited by employees, but can only be manipulated by admin users.

```
class Employee
  has_many :experiences
  has_many :languages, through: :experiences
end

class Language
  has_many :experiences
  has_many :employees, through: :experiences

end

class Experience
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :language

  attr_accessible :employee_id, :language_id, :duration
end
```

I would like to be able to edit the attribute duration on experience on a form, having a checkbox to make the association itself, and some input for experience.

**Edited**

I do not want the dynamic nested attribute solution, but something like this,
point being that I want to show all the association choices in checkbox format, not a dropdown.

[image]

I know this is straying from the usual, but there are UI constrains that call for it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use nested model, so for example, if you are editing an employee information, you can add experience (language and duration).

Check these RailsCasts http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+model

You have to edit your Employee model so it can admit a nested model (in this case Experience), and you have to allow mass assignment for the attributes of Experience. This way:

Employee

```
attr_accessible :experiences_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences, allow_destroy: true
```

And for the views:

The form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @employee do |f| %>    
  <%= f.input :name %>

  <hr />

  <h3>Experience</h3>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :experiences do |pf| %>
     <%= render 'experience_fields', f: pf %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_fields "New employee experience", f, :experience %>

  <hr />

  <div>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The partial experience_fields

```
<fieldset>
    <%= f.association :language %>
    <%= f.input :duration %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "Remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Check the RailsCasts, specially http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2, and if you have a premium account check http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Remember to add the Javascript functions and the helpers that are explained in the videos.

Also, watch this: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms

Comment: that would work, but I do not want several entries of C++ in the language model, I could have C ++, C plus plus, which could be complicating if I would want to have statistical counts later on

Comment: If I understand you well: you can add validations, so an employee will have only one experience per language, and the languages will be controlled in the Language model, so here you will be checking that only C++ exists, and the Experience model will only use the association (you are not creating languages here, only using them)

Comment: I've hacked a sudo form of what I want, this should clear up my intentions